# How to use different ports on single Tomcat instance which listens on a single port?

Tags: tomcat, webserver, virtualhost

Using a single Tomcat instance, which listens on a single port, how can I host multiple websites under different hostnames *and* port numbers?

### Example:

Let's say that the single tomcat instance is listening on a single port: At `localhost:9090`.

How can I configure Tomcat and/or my webpages in order for *both* of the following requests (which are sent to `localhost:9090`) to work?

### Request 1:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sample.com
```

### Request 2:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sample.com:120
```

Comment: Why do you need different ports?

Comment: @Stefan For learning. I suppose that it should be possible. So, I would like to learn how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Setup different connectors in conf/server.xml (don't choose ports below 1024):

```
....
<Connector port="80" connectionTimeout="20000" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
<Connector port="1234" connectionTimeout="20000" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

<Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina" jvmRoute="tomcat8">

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
    </Realm>

    <Host name="localhost"      appBase="webapps"           autoDeploy="true"unpackWARs="true"></Host>
    <Host name="www.sample.com" appBase="webapps-samplecom" autoDeploy="true"unpackWARs="true"></Host>
    ...

</Engine>
...
```

This will enable www.sample.com, www.sample.com:1234.

Comment: Will let you know after I get the chance to try it. Thanks.